# функция mysql возвращает больше одного значения

Tags: mysql, sql, функции

```
 DELIMITER $$
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `func_poster`(`nameP` 
    VARCHAR(200), `filmid` INT) RETURNS int(11)
    NO SQL
   BEGIN
    DECLARE idRow INT DEFAULT 0;
    INSERT poster (name) VALUES (nameP);
    SELECT id INTO idRow FROM poster WHERE name LIKE nameP;
    REPLACE poster (name, film_id) VALUES (nameP,filmid);
    RETURN idRow;
   END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

функция заполняет поле name и film_id (id связанной таблица ( связь один ко многим)

при повторном заполнении почему-то возвращает больше, чем одно значение, в этом и заключается проблема 
вот только в каком месте возвращается еще одно значение неясно

Comment: А зачем вы делаете replace ? от ведь удаляет старую запись и создает новую и у нее будет не тот же id, который вы получили на предыдущем шаге. в чем хитрость такого подхода, чем его поведение должно отличаться от `insert into poster(name, film_id) values(nameP,filmid); return last_insert_id();`

Comment: replace решал эту проблему в других функциях, это-то и странно
просто там он заполнял таблицы film_has..
здесь же связь "ко многим"
(а так я пробовал убирать вовсе строчку с replace, но это не помогло)

Comment: А вообще функция физически не может вернуть более одного значения, смотрите как вы ее вызываете, может делаете это несколько раз. И очень рекомендую перестать использовать `like` вместо `=` вы создаете себе в системе проблемы с безопасностью. Задав вместо имени знак `%` можно угробить всю БД например ...

Comment: % ведь можно экранировать, разве нет?
есть предположение, что в idrow пишется несколько значений

Comment: А зачем его экранировать, если можно написать просто `SELECT id INTO idRow FROM poster WHERE name = nameP`. Несколько значений в INT не могут быть записаны

Comment: но возвращает ведь несколько

Comment: А как это выглядит. как вы вызываете функцию и куда они выводятся ?

Comment: `foreach($post[$i] as $key => $pp) {
   $command = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT func_poster(:name, :film)")
            ->bindValue(':name', $pp)
            ->bindValue(':film', $id)
            ->queryScalar();}

выглядит это  так
`

Comment: И как на основе этого вы понимаете, что значений вернулось несколько ?

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, проблема в

```
SELECT id INTO idRow FROM poster WHERE name LIKE nameP;
```

а именно, имя (name) не является уникальным.